# How to validate if an HTMLLIElement is hidden with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating through a variable called content, it contains several HTMLLIElement objects.
How can i use jQuery's or JavaScript's functions with this object?, what I'm trying to do is the kind of validation written in the commented code.

```
    $.each(content, function(index, value){
         //if(!value.is(':hidden')){
              console.log(index + ' : ' + value);
         //}
    });
```

What I'm getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'is'

If I do `value.getAttribute('style');` I get `'display: none;'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in your `$.each` function references a DOM `HTMLLIElement` element. To apply a jQuery method such as `is` to it you have to wrap your `value` element inside a jQuery object:

```
if(!$(value).is(':hidden')) {
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/GCxyr/1/).

As noted by @anonymousdownvotingislame, `if($(value).is(':visible'))` may be more readable as the human brain tends to have difficulty interpreting double negations, let alone you don't have to use the not `!` operator. Thanks. `=]`

Comment: Do `if($(value).is(':visible'))`.

Comment: Just corrected myself, erm I must've been really tired when I wrote this answer, glad it worked w/o the long explanation. `:P` Thanks @anonymousdownvotingislame.

Answer (score 1):

Value isn't a jQuery object.

Try:

```
$.each(content, function(){
         if($(this).is(':hidden')){
              console.log(index + ' : ' + value);
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$content.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
        console.log("whatever");
    }
});
```

... or just do:

```
$.each(content, function(index, value) {
    if (value.getAttribute("style") === "display: none;") {
        consoloe.log("whatever");
    }
});
```